# automatic split cell text in google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

any formula or script to automatic split cell text in google sheet for ex:

i have text in cell A and i want to split text in Cell B

if cell A with this value (http://example.com/?/http://demo.com)  then in cell b i need demo.com automatic ..

```
         Cell A              ----------------              Cell B

http://example.com/?/http://demo.com                     http://demo.com

http://example.com/?/http://aol.com                      http://aol.com   

http://example.com/?/http://bbc.com                      http://bbc.com
```

but also i want that Cell a contain true value . imean i dont want to change cell a value if cell a contain  `http://example.com/?/http://demo.com`   after split this value remain same in cell A ..

thanks i hope you understand my question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the split formula so:

```
=SPLIT(A1,"?/",FALSE)
```

You could also do this in a single function without having to copy down by using arrayformula and regexextract:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"\?\/(.*)$"))
```